# Software algorithm or hardware chips for fixing audio feedback loop

Tags: microphone, feedback

I'm supposed to do a presentation on solutions to fix audio feedback loop (microphone feedback, that issue when you hear the voice echoed multiple times) and I can't find any algorithms for software based solution and also can't find any hardware circuits.

I tried looking for books, whitepapers but can't find anything.
Also tried looking on microsoft websites on the windows features but can't find anything technical.

All I need is just the name of the algoritms and of the circuits.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for some kind of office/online conference solution, for which the fix is always 'wear a headset'. For live solutions, feedback suppressors abound - https://www.thomann.de/gb/sp_feedback_controllers.html

Comment: Hi, when I said that I will do an presentation I meant that I'm a student and this is the topic software algoritms and hardware chips to prevent the feedback loop.
Thanks for the link I will try to find the spreadsheets of those products to see how they work.

Comment: For algorithmic structures you may do better asking on [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you, great suggestion I will post there for the software side.

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is closer to _echo cancellation_ than _feedback loop_ ?